# How to match Access and Excel records and update Access database?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a column with vendor name in an Access table which updates every day (from blank to name) with respect to delivery number (unique).

Every day I want to extract the data from SAP and update the records whose vendor name got updated in System.

I need a SQL query which will match the delivery numbers in Access and Excel workbook and according from Excel work it will capture name of vendor and update Access database.

I have written code that can update only one name at a time, but I want to update everything in one go.

```vb
Sub Update()
    Sheets("Carrier Updated").Select

    'Initialize all variables
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String, stProvider As String

    Dim X As Variant

    X = Range("A2").Value

    Dim Y As Variant

    Y = Range("B2").Value

    stDB = "C:\Users\yemdema\OneDrive - Ecolab\Desktop\Drive - A\Delivery Creation\DB Backup\Test_1.accdb"
    stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

    'Opening connection to database
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = stDB
        .Provider = stProvider
        .Open
    End With

    'SQL Statement of what I want from the database
    stSQL = "UPDATE Delivery_Creation set [Carrier Updated Later] = '" & Y & "' where[Delivery] = '" & X & "'"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(stSQL)
    MsgBox ("Carrier has been updated")

    'Looping through the records I pulled and inserting the data into the comboBox
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the field types for `[Carrier Updated Later]` and `[Delivery]`? Also, you need a space after the word `where`.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have different values for X and Y for each pair of values found in the worksheet, you can either update one set (as you do now), or collect these in a (temporary) table and call an update query using that table. No big difference, though.

Or you could "reverse" the process, using *Access* to link the range in the worksheet as a linked table, and then run an update query using that table.